# How to connect RedBearLab BLE shield (Or how to find Nordic_nRF8001.h)?

Tags: bluetooth, ble

I am trying to explore the possibilities of connecting an Arduino to Phonegap/Cordova. I have a RedBearLab BLE Shield, which I want to test the connection with. My MVP would be to get the value of a PIN to a Cordova app. Nevertheless, I couldn't make it even close.

The closest I got, it was using Don Coleman's [Phonegap plugin](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central).
I am trying his [Simple Chat example](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central/tree/master/examples/redbearlab).

With this example the sketch is attempting to include `Nordic_nRF8001.h`. Nevertheless, I can't seem to find this library. I downloaded it from various sources, but no matter what I do, my sketch still can't find the file.

The only way I could make it work was via CodeBender, but then the readings were a bit of a mess.

I'm not expecting anyone to do all the work for me, so if you can help me in one of the two directions, it would be awesome:

1. Figure out why I can't find that Nordic_nRF8001.h file.
2. Or help me find another method of BLE communication.

**Later edit**
Using the examples that come with RBL library, I figured out the name of the files I need to use. Now I'm running into another problem for which I opened [a new question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/74595/simplechat-ble-example-prints-scrambled-characters).

Thank you!

Comment: I tried using the web editor. There I could find the SimpleChat example, with the correct names of the libraries. They work perfectly.

Comment: The scrambled characters issue was because of the wrong Baud Rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Arduino Create Web Editor to load the SimpleChat example. It loads with these libraries, and it works perfectly:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <boards.h>
#include <RBL_nRF8001.h>
```

Thanks,
Andi