# SimpleChat BLE Example prints scrambled characters

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I am trying to use the SimpleChat application to test my RedBearLab Shield.
If I send "Hello" and to to Serial.print or Serial.write the return what I see in my Serial monitor is stuff like "Fh`Fx**-H3r:AJb6# E0CbJ"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you,
Andi Stancu

Comment: try changing the baud rate in the serial monitor

Comment: That most definitely fixed it! Thank you! Please add it as a solution so I can mark it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are transmitting `Hello` and receiving `Fh'Fx**-H3r:AJb6# E0CbJ`, then the problem is most likely a `baud rate mismatch`.

The receiver is sampling the data signal 3 or 4 times faster than it should.

Start by lowering the baud rate of the serial monitor to 1/4 of the current baud rate.

If that does not produce correct data reception, then start at the lowest baud rate and work your way up.